# Обработка жестов в Android

Tags: android-sdk, android

Как обрабатывать смахивания и жесты на представлениях?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Обработка жестов - тема очень обширная, здесь я попробую отметить только основные моменты.

Что касается сложных геометрических жестов (например жест - квадрат и тп.), то подход здесь следующий:

1. Для начала необходимо создать специальный файл, который будет хранить жесты и связывать их с идентификаторами. Создается такой файл с помощью утилиты *Gestures Builder*.
2. В самом приложении необходимо разместить на разметке слой, который будет "принимать" жесты:

   ```
   <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
               android:id="@+id/gestures"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
   ```
3. Регистрируем на этот слой слушатель `OnGesturePerformedListener`, который будет обрабатывать жесты и через колбэк `onGesturePerformed` возвращать идентификаторы распознаных жестов.

Подробнее смотрите, например, [эту статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120016/).

---

Для обнаружения простых жестов, вроде смахивания, все гораздо проще.

Вам нужно повесить слушатель `OnTouchListener` на свой элемент, который должен "понимать" смахивания. В колбэке интерфейса `onTouch()` регистрируется `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`, который позволяет переопределить метод `onFling()` - обнаружение смахивания - в этом методе вы определяете логику действий при смахивании. Так же интерфейс распознает еще [несколько действий](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html): скроллинг, долгое касание и некоторые другие

Простой [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4098447):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private void onCreate() {
        final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());
        final ImageView imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
                gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }               

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                return false; // справа налево
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                return false; // слева направо
            }

            if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                return false; // снизу вверх
            }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                return false; // сверху вниз
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Более глубокое погружение в тему распознавания простых жестов - смотрите, например, [эту статью](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-mobileforthemasses2/index.html).

Comment: Премного благодарен!