# Распознавание жестов android

Tags: java, android, gestures

Как сделать программу, которая будет распознавать жесты? Пример: я открываю браузер, рисую на экране букву "G" и он мне открывает гугл.
Или просто перевод нарисованных мной символов на экране в буквы, цифры.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466257/177345